# KO 5 second delay runining my UI when loading

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am making a website and i am using KO JavaScript to show Log In and Register if the user is not logged in or Log out if the user is logged in. All the functionality works perfectly but my issue is when the page loads it shows all of them for a split 5 second until the entire page has loaded properly, then it triggers and inserts the correct statement. This does not look nice and i really want it to execute straight away, as its effect my UI. Anyone help?

Here is my code.

```
                <!--ko ifnot: Logged()-->
                   <a href="logged" class="ShowLogged">Log in</a>
                <!--/ko-->

                <!-- ko ifnot:Logged()-->
                   <a href="register" class="ShowRegister"> Register</a>
                <!--/ko-->

                <!-- ko if: Logged() -->
                   <a href="#" class="ShowLog" data-bind="click: Logged.Loggedout"> Log Out</a>
                <!--/ko-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `template` binding to render that part:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'logged-links'} -->
<!-- /ko -->

<script id="logged-links" type="text/html">
    <!--ko ifnot: Logged()-->
        <a href="logged" class="ShowLogged">Log in</a>
        <a href="register" class="ShowRegister"> Register</a>
    <!--/ko-->

    <!-- ko if: Logged() -->
        <a href="#" class="ShowLog" data-bind="click: Logged.Loggedout">
            Log Out
        </a>
    <!--/ko-->
</script>
```

Between the time elements are rendered by the browser and `ko.applyBindings` is called (5 sec in your case), `<!-- ko -->` bindings are ignored and your links are treated as normal html markup.

By putting those links in a `<script>` tag, the browser will not render them but knockout will do once `ko.applyBindings` is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That sorted it out!!

Comment: Also, another alternative would be adding a display property on the main div or the container i.e <div style="display:none" data-bind="visible:Logged"></div>. So this way the element is hidden until the binding kicks in. The down side to this is that you will have to add the style property on the element it self.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put knockout.js in header, so it loads before every rendering.

This should execute the logic as soon as it loads not after the whole page loads.

Comment: Yeah but i have a lot of knockout throughout my website and i would prefer a way where i can do something where its place which will stop this happening.. thanks for input anyway.

Comment: I mean to put the `<script src="knockout.js" ></script>` in before `</head>`. Just try that.

Comment: Nope still does it :(

Comment: Then you should try to make them all invisible at loading, and after everything loaded up, to show only what needs to be shown. A good technique for this is to use a loading overlay. Hope that helps.